# Stuck in an error where the app is not accepting input

Tags: python

So I am doing an assignment for my university for making a simple catering system on python. The part of the code where the issue is:

```
def other_services():
    global servicesCart
    services = [{"name":"1. Tent per 10 feet","price":400},{"name":"2. Chairs per 50 peices","price":50},{"name":"3. Tables per 10 pieces","price":80},{"name":"4. Table cloth per 10 peices","price":20}]
    print("Press E to exit")
    while True:
        for f in services:
            print("Name : ",f['name'],"Price : ",str(f['price']))
        selectedService = input("give your order")
        if (selectedService == "E"):
            cms()
        try:
            servicesCart.append(food_lunch[int(selectedService) - 1]) * (people)
        except:
            print("Wrong input, please try again.")}
```

The issue is that no matter what input I give, the output remains wrong input, please try again. The people in this is the number of guests that is asked in the beginning of the code and has an integer value. Any help will be greatly helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
servicesCart.append(food_lunch[int(selectedService) - 1]) * (people)
```

doesn't work: you're appending `food_lunch[int(selectedService) - 1]`, `append` returns `None` and you're multiplying `None` with `people` which triggers an exception:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Since you filtered *all* the exceptions, you get your error message, and you'll see that there's another error: you have to get "price" dictionary key

Fix:

```
    try:
        servicesCart.append(food_lunch[int(selectedService) - 1]["price"] * (people)]
    except Exception as e:
        print("{}, please try again.".format(e))
```

so if anything happens you get the actual error message instead of your generic (and wrong error message)

Here you probably want to catch `IndexError` from your list access. I suggest that you check the boundaries using `len` instead of a `try/catch` block.

```
idx = int(selectedService) - 1
if 0 <= idx < len(food_lunch):
    servicesCart.append(food_lunch[idx]["price"] * people)
else:
   print("invalid input")
```

That has the advantage of filtering negative indexes, that would be happily accepted by `[]` (end of list access) as long as their absolute value is within range, probably not what you want

Comment: error is "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'int', please try again."

Comment: at least the try/catch block was useful :) see my edit. I had overlooked your datatype

Comment: Ok so the error is gone, but the prices are not adding up, which is totally weird. After selecting, the individual arrays should add up, to sum up in a total, which will go to another module which has the total sum of the whole bill. When i see the report it shows 0, which means that the code is not calculating the integer value of individual parts of array. Hope it makes sense lol.

Comment: print `servicesCart` to see what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
                         # printing your products :
```

print("T for Tent\n C for chairs \n Ta for Tables \n Tac for clothes table")
                             #list of your priducts :
list_1 = {"T": " Tent per 10 feet its price : 400$","C": "Chairs per 50 peices its price: 50$","Ta" : "Tables per 10 pieces its price: 80$","Tac": "cloth table per 10 peices its price: 20$"}

```
                         #calling customer order :
```

while True:
    selectedService = input("give your order")
    if (selectedService == "E"):
        break
    elif selectedService in list_1:
            print(list_1[selectedService])
    else:
        print("your request is not available")